# Found a surprise wiring

Tags: ceiling-fan

About to exchange the ceiling fan, have not disconnected it.

The fan has 2 separate wall switches one for fan and one for light.

It is a simple fan without remote speed control (has a pull chain for that).

While I think I understand the wiring from looking from bottom, LIGHT, FAN, and 2 neutral together.

The last one (on the top) is a bit of surprise.

It has 2 black joined with ground wire?

[image: Fan]

The new Fan comes with Remote control.

How do I wire this, and what is it with 2 Black joined with Ground ?

PS: I am slightly color blind, so those might be dark green and not black, which would explain the confusion.

Comment: Are you sure they are black?  They look green to me.  From the bottom, black and white, blue with what I think is red painted white,  two white, and two green with a painted bare wire.

Comment: @crip659 did I say I am color blind :) not totally, I do see green and red traffic lights.

Comment: @Ruskes the two wires connected to the bare copper wire have green insulation ... the bottom most wire is black, compare them side by side

Comment: I do not like to trust stuff(colours) I see on a screen too much.  If they are green, then it should be good if the white painted wire is bare.  Taken another look at the bottom wires, what I thought as black and white, seem to be more black and black with white paint.

Comment: Your camera is color blind lol.  I looped your pic through Photoshop, the wires with the bare wire are green as the day is long.  These are individual wires in conduit, that's why there's writing on the side of them.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica No, the writing is on the fan/light wiring. The box is fed by /3 NM (red, white, black, bare). No evidence of conduit.

Answer (score 9):

Grouped from top to bottom in the photo you have:

- 2 Green from fan with 1 slightly paint-covered Bare from box (ground)
- 1 White from fan with 1 slightly paint-covered White from box (neutral)
- 1 Blue from fan with 1 slightly paint-covered Red from box (switched hot - likely light)
- 1 Black from fan with 1 slightly paint-covered Black from box (switched hot - likely fan)

Nothing out of the ordinary here.  Those two insulated wires on top are in fact green.

Comment: Almost there. Since the new fan comes with integrated light, I no longer need the wires for the light sitch. Find them and cap them off ? Correct. --> Green it is :)

Comment: Would not use slightly painted black, but I can be picky.